# yii ajax response right syntax

Tags: php, syntax, yii, response

I have action for **AJAX** request  in **YII**:

```
public function actionSomeCheck()
{
    if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar')
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
    }

    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'error'));
}
```

I need to add brakes after response generated, but didn't find right syntax.

It can be:

```
public function actionSomeCheck()
{
    if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar')
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
        die();// Or exit
    }

    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'error'));
    die();
}
```

or:

```
public function actionSomeCheck()
{
    if($_GET['foo'] == 'bar')
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
        return false;
    }

    echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'error'));
    return false;
}
```

or without any break after last respone.

Probably with **die/exit** it will return response faster, but can prevent some actions.

It's not a matter of life and death, but want to understand right syntax, as I'll use it very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to terminate a Yii application is with:

`Yii::app()->end();`

This will handle any `onEndRequest` events prior to calling `exit()` itself.

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#end-detail

Additional clarification:

It is not necessary to call `Yii::app()->end;` yourself at the end of a request. All that method does is handle `onEndRequest` events, and then call `exit()`.

Whereas when you run the application normally with `run()`, you see that `onEndRequest` events are handled by default before the application terminates normally.

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#run-detail

Comment: Just one clarification. Do I need to add it after last response or Yii automatically will do it?

Comment: @Narek I have updated my answer with the requested clarification.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer.

Comment: Note: adding an end statement is the normal Yii way. However, at the moment, it can cause problems if you have web logging turned on. In that case, sometimes it is actually better to have die in there :-)

Answer (score 1):

**use the switch case**

```
public function actionSomeCheck()
{
$data = $_GET['foo'];
switch($data)
         {
             case 'bar':
                 echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
             break;
             default:
                 echo CJSON::encode(array('status'=>'error'));
             break;

         }
}
```

Or you can add more cases.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is just simple example. In real code can be multiple checks in different places.

Comment: @Narek i give simplest form as you didnt mention multiple check..In that case you can use `Yii::app()->end();`